# Load data from database on select box onchange event

Tags: ember.js

Can anyone guide me how to load data from a database when I change the value in the select box? I tried the following code, but when I try to get the "value" and log it says "undefined."

My Component.js

```
actions:{
 filterStudent(){
   let filterInputValue = this.get('value');
   console.log(filterInputValue);
   let filterAction = this.get('filter');
   console.log(filterAction);
   }
}
```

My Controller

```
   actions: 
   {
     filterStudentResults(param) 
     {
       if (param !== '') 
       {
        return this.get('store').query('Students', { studentName: param });
       } 
       else 
       {
         return this.get('store').findAll('Students');
       }
     }
  }
```

My Component.hbs

```
<select name="newType" onchange={{action "filterStudent" value="target.value"}} class="form-control">
      <option value="" disabled selected>Please Select</option>
      {{#each model.Students as |newStudents|}}
         <option value="{{newStudents.studentId}}">{{newStudents.studentName}}</option>
      {{/each}}               
</select>
```

Am calling the component in the Specific template as

```
{{bind-dropdown model=model Filter=filterStudentResults}}
```

Am a newbie to EmberJS and appreciate any help. Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: Please be more specific than "not working."

Comment: when  i try to get the "value" and log its says "undefined" :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In My-Component.js, does not having `value` as property, You mean to get it from `onchange={{action "filterStudent" value="target.value"}}` then your action should receive param,

```
actions:{
 filterStudent(selectedValue){       
   console.log(selectedValue);       
   }
}
```

One more problem, I found upon sending action `filterStudentResults` to component.
The below one is wrong.
    `{{bind-dropdown model=model Filter=filterStudentResults}}`
As you have defined `filterStudentResults` in controller, you can create closure action and send it to component, so it should be like,

```
{{bind-dropdown model=model filter=(action 'filterStudentResults')}}
```

And it should be invoked with selectedValue from component action,

```
actions:{
     filterStudent(selectedValue){           
       this.sendAction('filter',selectedValue);//this will call controller method with param 
       }
    }
```

Comment: It's better using `sendAction` in case of `filter` is not being set. `this.sendAction('filter', selectedValue)`

Comment: hi am getting the error "this.get is not a function". what is that? can you please help ?

Comment: @Azmy I think you might be missing this part `{{bind-dropdown model=model filter=(action 'filterStudentResults')}}`  Note `filter` property name

Comment: @kumkanillam yes i missed it my bad!! now i get the selectedValue but my controller is not getting invoked am not getting any errors either can you please help :(

Comment: @Azmy so you need to ensure that `bind-dropdown` is included in the corresponding template hbs. Consider posting the template and controller code and file name in your question . you can even create minified verifiable example for your problem using http://ember-twiddle.com

Comment: @EbrahimPasbani Yes you are right. Thank you. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to check the model is ready and you can do so inside route's `afterModel(model)` hook.

```
<select name="newType" onchange={{action "filterStudent" value="target.value"}} class="form-control">
```

Should be re-write to,

```
<select name="newType" onchange={{action "filterStudent"}} value={{target.value}} class="form-control">
```

Comment: i tried wot you said and am still getting the same output :(. Can you please give me some more information?

Comment: Did you get `model` from the route's hook?

Answer (score 0):

My controller is not getting invoked from the component the sendAction method is not working.

MyController.js

```
 actions: 
 {
    filterStudentResults(param) 
    {
     if (param !== '') 
     {
       return this.get('store').query('Students', { studentName: param });
     } 
     else 
     {
       return this.get('store').findAll('Students');
     }
   }
}
```

am calling the component from the template as follows

```
{{bind-dropdown model=model filter=(action 'filterStudentResults')}}
```

My Component js

```
actions:{
  filterStudent(selectedValue){
    this.sendAction('filterPartsResults',selectedValue)
 }
```

My Componet file name is bind-dropdown and my contollers name is studentsController. The template name is list-studentDetails.

Comment: include the component code too. what is your template and controller file name ?

Comment: Template file name and controller file name should be same. if you included `bind-dropdown` in  `list-studentDetails` template then you need to define actions in ` list-studentDetails` controller file. I would encourage you to read https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.11.0/controllers/  and also prepare stand alone sample for demonstration in http://ember-twiddle.com

Comment: can anyone help me in how to access target value property of the selectbox onchange event ??

Comment: `onchange={{action "filterStudent" value="target.value"}}` it will provide selected value.this should work. nothing wrong in your code.. if you want `event` object to be passed for `filterStudent` function then consider `onchange={{action "filterStudent"}}` and first argument to filterStudent would be `event` object, you can use this to get `event.target`

Comment: By the way you can very well ask another question nothing wrong in it. As I said create ember-twiddle that will help us to figure it out what is wrong in your attempt ?.